# Pyaudio supports all formats, despite the fact the audio card does not

Tags: python, portaudio, pyaudio

I am attempting determine if a format (rate/depth) is supported on an audio card. I have found that pyaudio returns True regardless of rates and depths specified. How do I show only modes natively supported by the audio card? I have reproduced this on windows, mac, ubuntu, fedora. I have included a working snip of code to assist in solving this issue.

```
import pyaudio

pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()

try:
    default_device_id = pa.get_default_output_device_info()['index']
except IOError:
    print ("There is no default device")
    exit(1)
try:
    result = pa.is_format_supported(rate=48000, output_device=default_device_id, output_channels=2, output_format = pyaudio.paFloat32)
    print("Unexpected, device does not really support this result was: %s" % result)
except ValueError:
    print("Expected Unsupported Device")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the underlying API used by PortAudio. By using the default device you're most likely running on top of DirectSound when on Windows. DirectSound will basically tell PortAudio that any format it asks is supported, and then converts to what is natively supported by the hardware behind PA's back. The only way to get around is to instruct PA to use a lower-level host API such as ASIO or exclusive-mode WASAPI on Windows (and probably ALSA on *nix but I'm just guessing here).